# Copy (Import) Data from Oracle Database To Another

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I want to Copy a data from One oracle database to another.

I have checked Import/Export Utility but the problem is import utility doesn't support conflicts resolution techniques between rows.

For Example if there's a table in the source database have the same row key in the destination database. if i use 'Ignore' parameter with value = y, the destination table will have a duplicate rows.

I want to ask if there's another way to import data from oracle database to another with some mechanism of detecting the conflicts and resolve them?

Comment: What resolution are you thinking of? Not inserting the new data, overwriting the old data?

Comment: @David Aldridge the resolution may be overwriting or merging the 2 rows

Comment: @Dan Bracuk could u describe more

Comment: What's the difference between overwriting and merging?

Comment: Merging like taking data from field form source row and take values of another field from the destination form the result row

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using a database link from database A to database B. You can query the data from database B to insert into your database A tables. You are free to query whatever you want using SQL or PL/SQL.

More on database links:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm